# Rolling platform to support 4000lb

Tags: timber-framing

I have 4000lbs of fasteners that I want to put on a rolling "flat". I have tons of pine 2x6. The dimensions would be 3'x8'. The platform is 3/4" plywood.
I have four wheels that can handle that capacity (one in each corner).
Would anyone please offer suggestions on framing this? 
How many planks to run lengthwise (8') to support such weight?

[image: sketch]

Comment: The overall design will depend on how the wheels attach. If they are mounted on a plate that will be screwed to your flat, what are the dimensions of the plate?

Comment: 7 (6" spacing, on edge as joists are) would appear to do it IF you had their ends properly supported but there is the question of how you will get the wheels attached and support the ends of the frame. Beware of what happens when you get a 2-ton wheeled object on a surface that's not dead level - They are difficult to fight with and generally win. Likewise, hard to start and hard to stop. Several smaller things might be more managable....

Comment: Why do want this "rolling flat"? Is it meant to store the fasteners and move them around from time to time? (i.e., used over and over again). Or is this a one-time task of moving from point A to point B? If I were doing this once I would use pallets and rent a pallet jack. If I were doing this for a living I would own the pallet jack. If you are somewhere in between I would break up the task into smaller piles.

Comment: Thank you! 
The wheels have 4x4.5” plates. 
The warehouse floor is flat and level—I know what you mean about moving it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would frame it like a heavy-duty wall. Each side beam needs to support 2000 lbs. I calculate that three 2 x 6's are required on each side.

[image]

[image]

16 inch spacing of joists should be sufficient, use 12" to be more conservative.

And if you want it to be really strong, put plywood on *both* sides.

And I agree with Ecnerwal's comment, this thing will be a dangerous beast.

Comment: Dude, awesome! This is what I had calculated but only have three joists between the triple-threats. Is five really necessary with only 27” span? I also have blocks between the spans. 

Yes, it will be a beast! I need one “furniture piece because our product has so many different sized fasteners—it’s best to keep all in one place. And, because of changing inventories, and a constant “dance” of where it all goes, the wheels are necessary. 
Floor trolly and the forklift just wasn’t citrin’ it with the pallets. It became a nuisance. 
I’ll snap a pic after it gets built. 

Many thanks to all!

Comment: Less than 5 joists, i wouldn't trust nails (16d) alone. 4 joists (~19" span) with joist hangers should be OK. 3 joists (~24" span) with joist hangers probably won't break, but will be spongy. 24" spans in my attic with one big guy are slightly spongy, and your weights are higher.

Comment: Thanx! I agree.